# Windows sandbox flickering and unresponsive

Tags: windows-sandbox

I have tried Windows Sandbox on two different Windows 10 installations. On both PCs it flickers roughly every second and does not respond to user input. On one of them, I removed this feature, restarted and then re-enabled it after rebooting. It made no difference.

I haven't used it for a bit but feel sure it used to work.

Comment: I don't know about Sandbox on Windows 10 - Yes it used to work. Sandbox does definitely work here on Windows 11 Pro.

Comment: Windows 10 here, and Sandbox works fine for trivial tasks. What are you doing in it?

Comment: I can't do anything in it. It starts and then just flickers, I cannot get to the start menu, keystrokes don't work.

Comment: I have the same problem. I can confirm that it was definitely working ok for the last 2 weeks, but then for the last day, this flickering is there. I am very interested in a solution for this very frustrating bug.